# Return function with &&?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about this snippet from command pattern tutorial,

What does it mean by

`return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply( carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );`

Also I can understand if it is carManager.execute( "buyVehicle"), then carManager["buyVehicle"] can invoke the function, but what about carManager[buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "453543"]?

```
    (function(){

      var carManager = {

        // request information
        requestInfo: function( model, id ){
          return "The information for " + model + " with ID " + id + " is foobar";
        },

        // purchase the car
        buyVehicle: function( model, id ){
          return "You have successfully purchased Item " + id + ", a " + model;
        },

        // arrange a viewing
        arrangeViewing: function( model, id ){
          return "You have successfully booked a viewing of " + model + " ( " + id + " ) ";
        }

      };

    })();

    carManager.execute = function ( name ) {
        return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply( carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
    };

    carManager.execute( "buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "453543" );
```

Comment: && returns a boolean, so it's checking if both of those are truthy and returning true if they are

Comment: @zevee: No, `&&` can produce any type in JavaScript.

Comment: `&&` is the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) operator in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply( carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
```

if the function carManager[name] exists in the carManager then execute the function.

```
carManager[name].apply( carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
```

`.apply()` is used to invoke a certain function on someother or the same object. it takes the object as the first param and the arguments as the second param. you can provide any object as the first param as long as the function doent cause any change to the object's existing properties. for eg this works the same.

```
carManager.execute = function ( name ) {
  return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply( {}, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
};
```

code:

```
[].slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

`.call()` does pretty mush the same function as `apply()`. its taking the slice function of the Array object and invoking it on to some other object, this time on the arguments (object) array. `slice` returns a part of an array. in this case its just avoiding the first element in the arguments array. ie its making the array without the first element

```
carManager.execute( "buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "453543" );
```

it calls the invoke function. the first argument provides the key of the function. the second and the third arguments provide actual data that has to be passed into the method present in the carManager object. and thats the very reason why the arguments array was sliced.

Comment: why it is carManager[name] rather than carManager[name[0]]? carManager["buyVehicle"] vs carManager["buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "453543"]

Comment: name isnt the array of arguments. its a ref to the arguments[0]

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the example:

```
return f && f();
```

The way the `&&` operator works in JavaScript is by producing its left operand if its left operand is falsy and its right operand otherwise. It also short-circuits, meaning that if the left operand is falsy, the right operand isn’t evaluated at all. Here, it has the effect of calling `f` if `f` is truthy (e.g. a function) and returning its return value, or returning `f` if `f` is falsy (e.g. `undefined`).

In other words, it’s a short way of writing:

```
return f ? f() : f;
```

with the actual meaning of:

```
if (f) {
    return f();
}
```

and when `carManager` is an object with function properties, that in turn means calling the method named `name` only if it exists and passing on its return value.

---

> Also I can understand if it is carManager.execute( "buyVehicle"), then carManager["buyVehicle"] can invoke the function, but what about carManager[buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "453543"]?

This question is a bit hard to interpret but

```
carManager.execute("buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "453543")
```

probably answers it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a guard against the possibility that `carManager[name]` is a falsy* value (most likely not filled in at all). The code is assuming the property is either missing entirely or has a falsy value, or has a function in it.

If `carManager[name]` is falsy, it returns that falsy value.

If `carManager[name]` is not falsy (truthy), the code assumes it's a function and calls it (via `apply`) and returns whatever it returns.

---

* "falsy" = `false` if coerced to boolean. The falsy values are `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`. All other values are *truthy*.

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1

When you do:

```
return carManager[name] && carManager[name].func();
```

You are saying: check if `carManager[name]` is [untruthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). If it is, return false. Otherwise, execute the `func()` and return its result.

## Question 2

The [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) can be used to get all the arguments passed to a function, even if they aren't present in the function declaration.

```
function foo(baz) {
  console.log(arguments[0]); // outputs baz: "me"
  // same of: console.log(baz);

  console.log(arguments[1]); // outputs "you"
  console.log(arguments[2]); // outputs "them"
}

foo('me', 'you', 'them'); // call the function, pass 3 arguments
```